# Why are moles (quantity of a gas) and temperature inversely related?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm learning about the combined gas law, and while doing calculations, I found that a doubling in the quantity of moles causes the temperature to be cut in half (all other things being equal).

I don't understand the mechanics of the change. Why does twice as much gas in the same amount of space cause the temperature to drop?

I would assume that there would be no change, since the total heat mass of the gas is unchanged. The particles in the gas are moved closer together, true, and more influenced by intermolecular bonds; but that seems to cut both ways, as a more crowded cluster of particles might produce more collisions? All in all, I understand the formula, but I don't get how the particles are interacting.

Also, is it true to say, mechanistically, that an increase in volume *produces* an increase in temperature? I don't understand how that would work, but it seems like a parallel to the example above (particles with less space to move have less energy; you can either shrink the container or crowd it, and reduce the temperature accordingly).

I understand how Charles' Law works in the other direction: increasing temperature gives the particles more energy, which causes them to collide harder and more frequently with their container, which will then expand.

But does merely making a container larger cause the gas within to rise in temperature? How would more space increase the total heat mass contained within the system? Where is the extra energy coming from?

A decrease in V causes an increase in P, and an increase in P causes an increase in T, but a decrease in V does *not* increase T?

I would appreciate your help very much, this is driving me a little crazy.

ps. Down voting questions is rather ungenerous. It's a question, not an assertion. I am confessing that I don't understand. If I know too little to ask the question well, forgive me. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent not satisfying answers, misunderstanding, objections, question downvoting or closure

Comment: For your awareness:
Quantities: length, mass, amount // unit names:  metre, kilogram, mole // unit symbols: m, kg, mol

Comment: Okay, where have I gone wrong with that above? The quantity of a gas = the mass or amount of it. Moles are the most common unit used to denote a quantity of gas. Is it wrong to say heat mass? I thought I read that in a definition of enthalpy. I could just as well say total kinetic energy, but the two seem synonymous.

Comment: You should include in questions a short conclusion with eventual quotes/links from prior info searching, so others do not write things you already know, or you should know if you searched about it. If nothing was found, write at least what you have searched for. // Aside of general keyword search, search also with the search modifier `site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR inurl:hyperphysics keywords` to find similar topics on the respective sites.

Comment: This actually belongs on Physics.SE rather than on Chemistry.SE. And the true answer is that you are using the logical flow of the formula wrongly.

Comment: Ahh, okay, naturallyInconsistent, that sounds like an answer! Thank you! Could you explain a little more, even if it's a physics problem?

Comment: It's not a forum, but Q&A site - we primarily collect questions and answers that are valuable.

Comment: That's what I said? And you didn't answer my question, just implied it was stupid. That's not a very generous attitude for a teacher to have.

Comment: Before why, ask if.  As $n = \frac{pV}{RT}$, doubling gas amount is doubling $\frac{pV}{T}$.  There are 2 degrees of freedom, you can independently control 2 of 3 state variables and the 3rd is determined by the other 2.

Comment: Okay, that's an answer, and I appreciate it, but it's describing the formula, not the particles. Can you describe what the particles are doing such that moving them closer together decreases the temperature? Either by crowding them in a smaller container or doubling the quantity in the same container.

Comment: There is no sense of answering questions that start with false premises.  Amount of a  gas and temperature are not inversely  related.

Comment: Well, that's what I expected. But then I did a question for my course and a doubling in the quantity of gas halved the temperature. Not so?

Comment: We had a problem in which pressure and volume were unchanged, the number of moles doubled (from 1 to 2), and the initial temperature was 298K. We were asked to calculate final temperature. The result is 149K. When the formula is rearranged, n2 is the denominator, while n1 is the numerator along with T1; so that explains why the temperature will be halved. If all other factors remain constant, and moles are doubled and temperature halves, that seems like an inverse correlation. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You can ask this question for several intensive and extensive quantities where the relationship between is simply intuitive : why the temperature and the volume are inversely related, why the velocity and the time are inversely related, why a frequency and a mass are inversely related.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the equation

$$pV = nRT$$

If we double the amount, then to keep in the fixed volume $V$ the initial pressure $p$, you have to set the half of the initial absolute temperature.

$$pV = (2n)R(\frac{T}{2})$$

Because for constant volume and temperature, it would have the double pressure:

$$(2p)V = (2n)RT$$

But that does not mean the doubling the amount decreases temperature.

Comment: What is the R? They aren't using that in my course. And ahh, I think I've understood.

Comment: And yeah, I was drawing the wrong conclusions, which is what had me so puzzled. That relationship between n and T did not make sense to me (because it was wrong). So, what you're saying is, if you want to keep pressure constant, while doubling quantity, and the container can't change size, then something's got to give, and that's temperature. Alright, thanks.